# Why is the Functor instance for (,) mapping on the second value?

Tags: haskell, tuples, functor

In Haskell, the Functor instance of (,) is apparently

```
instance Functor (,) where
    fmap f (a,b) = (a,f b)
```

This results in the unintuitive fact that:

```
> fmap (const 5) [1, 2]
[5,5]
> fmap (const 5) (1, 2)
(1,5)
```

Now, using this definiton would work much better, in my opinion:

```
instance Functor (,) where
    fmap f (a,b) = (f a,f b)
```

It would work like this:

```
> fmap (const 5) (1, 2)
(5,5)
```

Why is it not like this?

Comment: How would you define `fmap succ ("Hello!", 42)`?

Comment: Because `class Functor (a :: * -> *) where ...` so it expects a type parameter, and the order of the type parameters is `data (,) a b = (a, b)`.

Comment: Have you tried writing `data MyTuple a b = MyTuple a b` (so that you can give a fresh instance), translating your proposed instance to `MyTuple`, and seeing what the compiler says? The sequence of errors you get should be quite enlightening.

Comment: Well it's just because functors are defined on a single type and tuples are there to contain multiple types. Hence... only one of them can get effected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instance is actually not `instance Functor (,)` like you said. That wouldn't be well-kinded:

```
Prelude> :k Functor
Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
Prelude> :k (,)
(,) :: * -> * -> *
```

i.e., `(,)` takes two type arguments (the types of both tuple-fields) to construct a tuple-type, but the `Functor` class is actually for type-constructors that take only *one* argument, like

```
Prelude> :k []
[] :: * -> *
Prelude> :k IO
IO :: * -> *
```

So why is there a functor instance at all? Frankly, I think this is one of the instances which should *not* have been defined, precisely because it's confusing that tuples aren't symmetric. However, it *can* actually be defined and there's only one way to do it, so this choice by the standard libraries is certainly not *unreasonable*. The trick is currying: you can partially apply the `(,)` constructor to any fixed left-field type, and that gives you then a single-argument type constructor. For example

```
Prelude> :k (,) Int
(,) Int :: * -> *
```

so you can for instance have

```
instance Functor ((,) Int)
```

Clearly it doesn't depend on what concrete type the left field has, so you can as well make it

```
instance Functor ((,) a)
```

In value-level Haskell, this section would be written

```
instance Functor (a,)
```

Unlike at the term level, partial application does *only* work for the leftmost argument (the section `(,b)` would actually be be sugar for `\a -> (a,b)`, but there are no type-level lambdas in Haskell), so `instance Functor ((,) a)` is the only instance that's possible here.

To get the behaviour you asked for, i.e. function applied to both/all fields, you need both fields to actually have the same type. I.e., you need a type constructor that has only one argument to begin with, and just uses that type twice for the fields of its *value* constructor. A standard type with that behaviour is [`V2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.7/docs/Linear-V2.html).

Comment: I feel like this particular `Functor` instance begins to make a bit more sense (especially regarding its utility) when you start to get to its `Applicative` and `Monad` instances (so that, for @MarkNeu, might be something worth keeping in mind for a little later on).

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is available from the [`Product`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html#v:Pair) functor:

```
Data.Functor.Product Data.Functor.Identity> fmap (+1) (Pair 5 6) :: Product Identity Identity Integer
Pair (Identity 6) (Identity 7)
```

As you can see, the key difference between `Product` and `(,)` is that both elements of the `Pair` have the same leaf type (in this case, `Integer`). (Relatedly: note that in the type above, `Integer` is mentioned just once, whereas in the type of `(5,6)`, `Integer` is mentioned *twice*.) Since `(,)` may contain completely unrelated types, there's no guarantee that you can apply a single function to both parts in a well-typed way.